# Are functions inside GUI code or Level-2 S-functions nested?

Tags: matlab, nested-function

Functions inside m-files for GUIs or inside m-files for Level-2 S-functions are written without `end` keywords.

Does this means all functions are nested into each other and, consequently, all variables of functions below are accessible for functions above?

Or this syntax is just a plain set of functions with `end`-s omited?

How does Matlab distinguish a syntax?

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/function.html) on functions:

> You can declare multiple local functions within the same file, or nest
>   functions. If any function in a file contains a nested function, all
>   functions in the file must use the `end` keyword to indicate the end of
>   the function. Otherwise, the `end` keyword is optional.

I believe the same applies for GUIs and S-functions. I find nested functions particularly useful for GUIs as a nested function can access the data (workspace) of its parent function without having to pass the variables as arguments.